# Can I create an AWS ECS cluster that uses a custom VPC?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-ecs

So after much time trying to get an AWS ECS cluster to recognize my instances, I realized it was the because the cluster was in the default cluster for the account while the instances were in a custom VPC.  I am able to get my instances registered with the cluster if I use the default VPC instead of the one I created so I know that's not the problem.

How do I specify that the cluster is in a created VPC rather than the default?  Basically, I want my instances in "VPC-x" to get recognized/registered by the ECS cluster.   Is that even possible?

Comment: Clusters aren't associated with a VPC.  This sounds like a networking issue.    Do you assign public IPs to the instances in your VPC?  If not, does the VPC have a NAT instance or gateway?

Comment: I did assign public IPs.  Like I said, I created the exact same instance with the exception of the VPC it was in.  The instance in the default VPC was discovered by the cluster, the other was not discovered.